# 14.04 updated to 14.10 sound issues, system settings > sound grays out

Tags: sound, media-buttons

Updateing 14.04 to 14.10 brought on a host of issues for me and my dell m6800, part of me wants to just reinstall 14.04, took me over a week to get my code env set though.

This issue is the sound the media keys are not working, they were listed under `xinput --list` however they are not there now. Also in top bar the sound symbol is not there I have no way to adjust volume other then going in the system settings sound. which would grey out until I ran this 
these commands.

```
sudo service pulseaudio stop
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo service pulseaudio start
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem in Ubuntu 12.10 ,while upgrading from 12.04, as your machine is a dell I think your one is realtek HD audio. So, you can download the source from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false and compile from the code following the instructions given with it. Then install it. I hope it will work then :) . As i said , the probable reason is your audio driver is broken.

Comment: Hey thanks seems to be working now my systems has a bunch of issue I get about 10 system errors when I log in. will have to move though each one, one at a time. not sure what I did to fix it, opened skype and audio started working again. Then next time it was down, now it seems to be back again I did a bunch of updates and upgrades. idk will keep this in mind and I'm sure the issue is not resolved.